# Finding deltatime in C# using stopwatch

Tags: c#, timespan, stopwatch

I'm trying to write a fixed timestep.

```
        Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        TimeSpan dt = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1/50);
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

        while(window.IsOpen())
        {
            timer.Restart();
            elapsedTime = timer.Elapsed;

            while(elapsedTime > dt)
            {
                window.DispatchEvents();

                elapsedTime -= dt;

                gameObject.FixedUpdate(deltaTime goes here as double);
            }
         }
```

I want to pass dt as argument to FixedUpdate as a double, is there a way to convert it somehow?

I'm also not quite sure about this line `TimeSpan dt = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1/50);` Basically I want dt to hold 1/50th of  a second.

Comment: `pass dt as argument to FixedUpdate as a double` - as double of what? Milliseconds?

Comment: And regarding 1/50: `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0/50);`

Comment: TimeSpan dt = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1/50); 1/50th of a second. Printing dt to console shows that it doesn't contain anything, it prints 0 so I don't think TimeSpan.FromSeconds does what I want it to do. The MSDN doc suggests it does, but it doesn't. :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without knowing the internals of FixedUpdate, you probably want [TotalMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
TimeSpan dt = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0/50.0);
TimeSpan elapsedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
while(window.IsOpen())
{
    timer.Restart();
    elapsedTime = timer.Elapsed;
    while(elapsedTime > dt)
    {
        window.DispatchEvents();
        elapsedTime -= dt;
        gameObject.FixedUpdate(dt.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Oh, just poor eyesight on my part then.

I'm testing the code and well it kind of works.

it doesn't enter the second loop if I go (elapsedTime > dt), so FixedUpdate is never called...

Comment: Here we go, I did it like this instead: `TimeSpan dt = TimeSpan.FromTicks(50)` and now it seems to work.

Comment: The loop here will never work, as you restart the timer on every iteration of the outer while loop. Meanwhile, the inner while loop relies on the elapsed time of the reset timer, which will always be 0 (or nearly 0) which will never be greater than dt. Thus, you'll always end up skipping the inner loop and restarting the timer again.

Comment: @B.Roth you're right, and good catch. Sometimes I amaze myself with my mistakes :) Worse, the poster accepted my bug, so I can't delete this! Anyone reading this, please do not copy and paste my code here, there's a bug.

Comment: I submitted an edit that should fix the logic, so if that gets approved then future viewers will be able to copy-paste the code and have it work.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding this part `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1/50)`**.  `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` accepts `double`, `1/50` is `int`(`int`/`int` gives `int` w/o floating point part), and its value is equal to `0`, when passed to method this values gets implicitly converted to `double` and eventually you get: `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1/50) -> 00:00:00`

To make it right, you have to work with `double` from the beginning and use `1.0/50`(1.0 is double):
`TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0/50) -> 00:00:00.0200000`

**Regarding this one: `gameObject.FixedUpdate(deltaTime goes here as double);`**
I assume you want to pass milliseconds as and argument value. For that you can write:

```
gameObject.FixedUpdate(dt.TotalMilliSeconds);
```